# FullCalendar v1.6.0 Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following code which works in FullCalendar v2.4.0:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    center: 'title',
    left: 'nothing',
    right: 'nothing'
  },
  selectable: false,
  defaultView: 'month',
  titleFormat: 'MMMM',
  events: [{
    start: "2018-03-01",
    end: "2018-03-01",
    rendering: "background",
    color: "red"
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5x2dL5Ls/74/

How could I do the same but with FullCalendar v1.6.0? (I have to do it with that version :-/)

Comment: sorry, which part is the problem in 1.6? It's not clear which of the code above you're talking about?

Comment: OK, thanks for answering. The code above works when I use FullCalendar v 2.4.0, but when I use FullCalendar v1.6.0 it does not work. And I have to work with version 1.6.0

Comment: Yes I know you said it doesn't work, but that's a bit vague. _which bit_ doesn't work exactly? Are you getting an error message? What happens if you each of the options in turn? Have you checked the documentation to see which options are supported in 1.x and which are not? You can narrow down the problem please.

Comment: Hi, this is the link of the code that does not work, to explain myself better. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5x2dL5Ls/77/). I want to paint a specific date in the calendar.

Comment: So it's the "rendering" option which is the problem? Why didn't you just say that in the question?? It's quite simple to mention that detail? Now your answer is delayed by several days for lack of a very simple explanation.

Comment: Anyway, the reason it doesn't work is because it's not supported: see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object (current version) vs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/event-object (v1). In v1 there's no such thing as Background Events.

Comment: Now, what's your real goal here? Do you want to highlight a specific _day_, or is it the specific _event_ you want to highlight? You achieved it using a background event, but is it really the day or event itself which you want to highlight?

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I want to highlight a specific day, or rather, I want to highlight several days of the year.

Comment: I had to update the version of FullCalendar to the current one (3.9.0), and I was able to get it. Thanks for everything.

Comment: No problem. Next time, read the documentation :-)

Comment: One last question, How can I change the color of the highlighted day's text ?, I tried with textColor: '#ff0000', inside events, but it does not work. What should I do? (I know my English is not very good)

Comment: well that property changes the event's text, and in your example above your event has no title, so there's no text to change. And the title is not normally displayed for background events anyway. Are you talking about changing the colour of the number on the day? Remember  you're doing this by making an event, you are not really changing the day itself at all, that's just an appearance.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fullcalendar+change+day+background+color&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=qB-xWvrjC7LL8gfEnrqYCw&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl some of the links in that result might give you a better way to achieve your goal. If nothing solves it then please ask a new question about it with your current code.

Comment: But if I want to change the color of the highlighted day number.

Comment: thanks bro.. you're great.! :-)

Comment: Also https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-GB%3AIE-SearchBox&dcr=0&ei=qB-xWtG1F8mysQGSwpeYAg&q=fullcalendar+change+day+text+color&oq=fullcalendar+change+day+text+color&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i8i13i30k1.231711.232179.0.232300.5.5.0.0.0.0.172.252.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.1.171....0.thcFzs7rzJg (changed search to the "text" colour instead of background colour). But really the search terms are not hard to think of, it's just searching exactly the thing you want to do....